# Regex for footbal score format

Tags: c#, regex

I want to write a regular expression for the score format which is used in many games like football.

0-2 (where 0 is the score for Team A and 2 is the score for Team B) Note: The hypen is required.

I have tried many regex but the following is working fine for almost all scenarios -

```
[0-9]-[0-9]+$
```

So -

```
0-2 -> True
100-200 -> True
a-a -> False
1-a -> False
1--2 -> False (Negative integer not allowed for right team)
```

The only scenario not working is - 
-1-2 (Negative integer for team A)

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Javed

Comment: So you want it to match `- -1-2`? Or `-1-2`?

Comment: i want it to not match either - -1-2 OR -1-2. It should only match

PositiveNumber-PostiveNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want it to allow negative scores for team A, then you need a `^` to specify that the first digit portion (`[0-9]`) must be the beginning of the line:

```
Regex.IsMatch("-1-2", "^[0-9]+-[0-9]+$") // False
Regex.IsMatch("11-2", "^[0-9]+-[0-9]+$") // True
```

*Note:* I also added an extra `+` on the left side (which was probably missing) so it'll scores that have multiple digits, like `11-2`.

Comment: this will work for negative scenario, but it fails even '11-2' (without the single quotes). Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Just need to add a '+' after the first team's score ^\d+-\d+$

Answer (score 3):

There are two components you need:

- Don't match negatives
- Match any number of digits

Together, the simplest regex for this is:

`^\d+-\d+$`

This will match any set of digits on either side; it will preclude negatives, and other symbols and characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match within a string (not beginning/end) use

`@"\b(?<!-)\d+-\d+(?!-)\b"`

Matches 100-200, 10-2, 5-60, but not -1-2, 1-a, -1-a, 1--a.
It will also match only the 0-1 in this string, but not AB0-1.

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/kI8pU3